# no se si el contolador no envia los datos o si las fetch api no los recibe

Tags: php, javascript, json, fetch

Hola amigos tengo esté código el cual inserta un usuario en la base de datos:Aclaro que está funcionando pero necesito que mi peticion fecth reciba el json que viene de php. Esto quiero hacerlo con el objetivo de jugar con las notificaciones:

```js
if ($errores=='success'){  
                $objUsuario=new Usuario();
                $objUsuario->setNombre($nombre);
                $objUsuario->setEmail($email);
                $objUsuario->setUsuario($usuario);
                $objUsuario->setPassword($password);
                $objUsuario->setRol($rol);

                $validar=$objUsuario->validateUsuario();               
                while($cantidad=$validar->fetch_assoc()):
                    if($cantidad['conteo']=='1'){
                        $respuesta=array(
                            'respuesta'=>'error',
                            'mensaje'=>'Este usuario ya existe'
                        );
                    }else{
                        $save=$objUsuario->save();
                        if ($save){
                            $respuesta=array(
                                'respuesta'=>'exito',
                                'mensaje'=>'Usuario registrado correctamente'
                            );
                        }
                    }
                endwhile;
            }elseif($errores!="success"){
                $respuesta=array(
                    'respuesta'=>'error',
                    'mensaje'=>$errores
                );
            }
        }
        die(json_encode($respuesta));
```

El código de fetch es:

```js
 //Peticion api
            fetch(`http://localhost/Facturacion/usuario/save`,{
                method:'post',
                body:datos
            })
            .then((res)=>{
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((data)=>{
                console.log(data);
            })
            .then(
                mostrarNotificacion('Usuario insertado','correcto'),
                this.reset()
            )
            .catch((error)=>{
            })
```

Como les decía al principio: El registro se inserta pero necesito los datos del json paa juga con las notificaciones.

Comment: Hola, puedes cambiar la linea "return res.json();" por "console.log(res); return res.text();" a ver si sale algo de texto de esta manera. A ver si podemos indentificar el problema.

Comment: Jonas me imprime el html como puedo evitar eso? porque yo creo que el poblema es ahí

Comment: Creo que te sobra una llave al final del archivo php,   donde *  } die(json_encode($respuesta)); prueba quitando esa llave  "}"